# Reduce json bean descriptor to text

Tags: json, jq

I wish to reduce with jq

```json
[ {
  "context" : "app:swagger,dev:8080",
  "parent" : null,
  "beans" : [ {
    "bean" : "app",
    "aliases" : [ ],
    "scope" : "singleton",
    "type" : "com.example.App",
    "resource" : "null",
    "dependencies" : [ "environment" ]
  }, {
    "bean" : "environment",
    "aliases" : [ ],
    "scope" : "singleton",
    "type" : "com.example.Environment",
    "resource" : "null",
    "dependencies" : [  ]
  }
},
...
}]
```

to

```
app --> environment
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem statement appears to be under-specified, but the following seems to be either a solution or very close to one:

```
jq -r '.[] | .beans[] | "\(.bean) --> \(.dependencies[])"' input.json
```